# Creating a table with scraped CSV data in R

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, web-scraping

I have the following `name_total = matrix(nrow = 51, ncol=3, NA)`, where each row corresponds to a state (51 being District of Columbia). The first column is a string giving the name of the state (for example: `name_total[1,1]= "Alabama"`). 
The second and third are urls of CSV files from the Census, respectively linking counties with the state senate districts, and counties with state house districts.

For Alabama:

```
name_total[1,2] ="http://www2.census.gov/geo/relfiles/cdsld13/01/co_lu_delim_01.txt"
name_total[1,3] ="http://www2.census.gov/geo/relfiles/cdsld13/01/co_ll_delim_01.txt"
```

I wish to get as a final output a table which would basically be all 50 states + DC with their respective counties and linked Senate and House districts. I don't know if that's very clear so here is an example:

```
       [,1]        [,2]             [,3]                [,4]              
[1,] "Alabama"  "countyX1"  "Senate District Y1"  "House District Z1"
[2,] "Alabama"  "countyX2"  "Senate District Y2"  "House District Z2"
[3,] "Alabama"  "countyX3"  "Senate District Y3"  "House District Z3"
[4,] "Alaska"   "countyX4"  "Senate District Y4"  "House District Z4"
[5,] "Alaska"   "countyX5"  "Senate District Y4"  "House District Z5"
```

I use a `for`loop:

```
for (i in 1:51){
  senate= name_total[i,2]
  link_senate = url(senate) 
  house= name_total[i,3]
  link_house = url(house) 
  state=name_total[i,1]
  data_senate= read.csv2(link_senate,sep=",",header=TRUE, skip=1)
  data_house= read.csv2(link_house,sep=",",header=TRUE, skip=1)
  final=cbind(state, data_senate, data_house)
}
```

Of course each element has a different number of rows, for Alabama (i=1) State returns "Alabama" once, the others returning respectively 3 by 122 and 3 by 207 matrices. I get an error message about these variations in the number of rows.

I'm pretty sure one of the issues is the use of the `cbind` function, but I do not know what to use to get a better result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case others have similar issues, I found a way to get what I wanted separately for State Senates and State Houses. First of all some of the States only have of the two, and the link for Oregon was down. Personally I took them out of my original data.

Then I initialized for the first state outside of the loop:

```
senate = url(name_total[1,2])
data_senate= read.csv2(senate,sep=",",header=TRUE, skip=1)
assign(paste("Base_senate_",name_total[1,1],sep=""),data_senate)
A = assign(paste("Base_senate_",name_total[1,1],sep=""),data_senate)

house= url(name_total[1,3])
data_house= read.csv2(house,sep=",",header=TRUE, skip=1)
assign(paste("Base_house_",name_total[1,1],sep=""),data_house)
B = assign(paste("Base_house_",name_total[1,1],sep=""),data_house)
```

and then I used `for` loop:

```
for (i in 2:48){
  senate = url(name_total[i,2]) 
  house= url(name_total[i,3])
  data_senate= read.csv2(senate,sep=",",header=TRUE, skip=1)
  assign(paste("Base_senate_",name_total[i,1],sep=""),data_senate)
  names(data_senate)[2] = "County"
  A = rbind(A,assign(paste("Base_senate_",name_total[i,1],sep=""),data_senate))
  data_house= read.csv2(house,sep=",",header=TRUE, skip=1)
  assign(paste("Base_house_",name_total[i,1],sep=""),data_house)
  names(data_house)[2] = "County"
  B = rbind(B,assign(paste("Base_house_",name_total[i,1],sep=""),data_house))
}
```

A and B give you the expected tables (without the string name of the State, but the first variable identifies the state).

I had to use the `names(data_senate)[2] = "County"` because the second column had a different name for some states.

Hope it helps!